# How can I visually estimate, or eyeball, the p-value of a histogram?

Tags: statistics, p-value

The question is: what is the approximate P-value for the investigation
of whether mother’s smoking during pregnancy has an effect on the length of gestation.

The p-value of this histogram is approximately 0.04 but I'm at a loss as to why

[image]

I assume I have provided sufficient context but if I have failed to provide necessary details, kindly let me know.
Big thank you in advance to all.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

1) What is the null hypothesis?

2) Given the null hypothesis, and the histogram of simulated samples, what is the probability that a random sample of mothers is as far away from the mean as the smoking mothers were?

(I'm blindly assuming that what the histogram shows is how far from the mean the simulated samples' means are.)